# TypeError in_array - Angular Manager::resolveDefaultModules - civicrm version 5.69.2

Tags: drupal

Just updated to CiviCRM 5.96.2 in a drupal 7 environment and got this error all of a sudden on only one of our domains (we're using multi-domain). Once it started i could access Civi at all using the affect domain. Very wierd. Anyone else experienced this issue?

> TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array,
> null given in in_array() (line 194 of
> .../civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php).

This is the code causing the issue. Essentially $module['basePage'] is null for one of the modules being looped through. I've temporarily stopped the error for occuring by adding an if is_array($modules['basePage']) on the value being passed.

```
  public function resolveDefaultModules($basePage) {
    $modules = $this->getModules();
    $result = [];
    foreach ($modules as $moduleName => $module) {
      if (in_array($basePage, $module['basePages']) || in_array('*', $module['basePages'])) {
        $result[] = $moduleName;
      }
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could find out which extension has the angular module with a `null` value for `basePages`. Can you grep for the string "basePages" on your server to find it?

Comment: Hi Coleman, 

I tried WATCHDOGing in the else condition of my hack but wasn't getting any results so I removed my hack and everything seems to be working again :-\

I'll post back here if i figure out what it was and it might affect the wider community. Presumably it was some configuration of ours

Comment: Hi @Coleman - there are many many ang.php files which do not specify a 'basePages'. We're going to add some more logging to see if we can pinpoint which ones is causing the fatal on our contribution pages (intermittently??).

Comment: It should be fine if the 'basePages' key is missing from the array, but not fine if it explicitly says `'basePages' => NULL` so check for any of those.

Comment: It's only every happening on the /transact/ path, and seems to include a large number of extensions. Rather than just the 'basePages' being missing, the whole of $module appears to be missing. We are print_r'ing the $module, but it's just empty, (not an empty array, just blank). Some module names which appear in our log:

af 
afformStandalone 
crmStatusPage 
jsonFormatter 
unvalidatedJwtDecode 

crmSearchDisplayTable 
ui.bootstrap
ui.sortable 
unsavedChanges 
crmAutosave

ngRoute 
crmQueueMonitor 
dialogService

Comment: could be related to this perhaps? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/604cca726c6a238e0530b5f660ab0e11596da090#diff-b26b657986ef8b8163e79bcaf85afe628f6d5457193253bc6ff4c009cca44bf5

Comment: So $moduleNames = $this->cache->get('moduleNames'); returns a list of module names. Then later it iterates over them and does: $angularModules[$moduleName] = $this->cache->get("module $moduleName"); but that doesn't exist in the cache, so it's just NULL.

Comment: Raised an issue here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue has been filed for this: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4969
with further discussion and some proposed fixes.

Comment: Thank you, Coleman!