# "Unrecognized Angular module" when creating a front-end accessible form

Tags: formbuilder

Curious if anyone else experience this issue?

I'm running WordPress 6.4.3 / CiviCRM 5.70.0 / PHP 7.4 on a VPS.  When I create a SearchKit search with a table (bypass permissions), then create a FormBuilder from the SearchKit table (Generic: Allow all users (including anonymous), with "accessible on front-end of website" checkbox checked), but WP throws the following error message when I access the form page either from an admin acount or guest:

---

**Fatal error:** Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Unrecognized Angular module afsearch03022024ChildColloquia. Please ensure that all Angular modules are declared. thrown in **/home/office/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php on line 160**

There has been a critical error on this website.

---

I looked at the FormBuilder | Search Forms listing, and "afsearch03022024ChildColloquia" is there.  I also installed the Angular Profile extension, but I'm still seeing the same error.  Curious if anyone knows what might be the issue?  Could it be because I'm still running PHP 7.4?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You don't need the deprecated Angular Profile extension (don't think it's the cause of this bug but it's definitely not a solution)

Comment: How are you accessing the form? Just by clicking the link to it? Or are you using a shortcode? If link, what URL is it giving you?

Comment: Getting similar after upgrading to 5.70 and creating a new Test form. Running PHP 8.2 Log file for PHP has: [21-Feb-2024 05:06:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Unrecognized Angular module afformTest. Please ensure that all Angular modules are declared. thrown in /home/xx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Angular/Manager.php on line 160 Public accessible form, and just returns blank white page. On Wordpress. Javascript error in developer tools shown below. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFT9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/

Comment: Interestingly, I disabled memcached in civicrm.settings.php file(turned to NoCache) and re-enabled and form now appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError in\_array - Angular Manager::resolveDefaultModules - civicrm version 5.69.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46379/typeerror-in-array-angular-managerresolvedefaultmodules-civicrm-version-5)

Answer (score 2):

This was tracked down to a caching bug and has been fixed: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29260

Released in the latest 5.69 and 5.70.